# Key aleatória durante a criação de usuário

Tags: php, sql, laravel, laravel-5, migrations

Na minha `migration` de `User` possuo: **nome**, **id**, **email** e **chave de autorização**, porém, gostaria de saber se é possível a **chave de autorização** seja criada aleatoriamente durante a criação do usuário, esse chave tem que conter ***6 caracteres***.

Por exemplo, quando o usuário é criado, a chave recebe automaticamente um `hash`:

(*12hj34* ou *user/32ej97*).

Existe algum recurso para isso?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A resposta anterior é boa, mas caso queira criar algo alfa número faça assim:

```
private function randomId()
{
    $permitted_chars = '0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
    $hash = substr(str_shuffle($permitted_chars), 0, 6);
    $validator = \Validator::make(['hash' => $hash], ['hash' => 'unique:users,hash']);
    if ($validator->fails()) {
        return $this->randomId();
    }
    return $hash;
}
```

Além disso é interessante você verificar se a chave é única antes de inserir no banco então eu gosto de colocar um `Validator`, assim eu executo novamente a função caso a chave já esteja salva e pego uma chave válida.

Answer (score 1):

Atualizando, basta integrar ao Laravel o [gladcodes/keygen](https://packagist.org/packages/gladcodes/keygen#) do repositório [gladchinda/keygen-php](https://github.com/gladchinda/keygen-php) e depois chamar:

```
return Keygen::numeric(8)->generate();
```

em uma função do `Controller` de usuários, fazendo que o `hash` seja salvo no banco de dados.

Comment: Uma alternativa é realizar apenas `\Illuminate\Support\Str::random(6)` sem a necessidade de um lib de terceiro.